# Using `Integrate` and or `FourierTransform`

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis, integral-equations

I have some general questions about `Integrate` and `FourierTransform`. Firstly with `FourierTransform` I am struggling to get anything meaningful from the result. For example: 
`w0 = 24.;`
`T = 0.2;`
`F = FourierTransform[Sin[w0 t] Exp[-t/T],t,w]` 
I get a result, but if I try and plot the absolute value of the result so `Plot[Abs[F],{w,0,100}]` I get nothing. In fact the `Abs[F]` just encapsulates the result of the `FourierTransform`.

So firstly, what am I doing wrong with `FourierTransform`?

If I however, do the Fourier transform manually with `Integrate` I have more success, so `F = Integrate[Sin[2. Pi nu0 ] Exp[-t/T] Exp[-I 2 Pi nu t],{t,0,Infinity}]`, I can easily take the absolute value and plot it -- getting the result I would expect!

This would be fine, but I want to play with my model, adding some complexity, for example `Integrate[Sin[2. Pi nu0(1 - Exp[-t/T]) ] Exp[-t/T] Exp[-I 2 Pi nu t],{t,0,Infinity}]` so now my resonance frequency itself is a function of time. However Mathematica returns a convergence error i.e. the new function does not converge on $0$ or $\infty$

Can anyone shed any light on my two problems?

---

---

Just for clarity, I have also constrained my integrals with assumptions such that `Assumptions-> w > 0 && t >0`.

Finally, using `Integrate` can take a huge amount of time for example

```
Integrate[
            Sin[2 \[Pi] \[Nu]0(1. - Exp[-t/\[Tau]]) t] Exp[-t/\[Tau]] Exp[- 2. I \[Pi] \[Nu] t ],
            {t,0, +Infinity},
            Assumptions->\[Nu] > 0 && t > 0
        ];
```

Comment: Are you trying to plot a delta function?

Comment: @chuy this won't be a delta function, or it shouldn't be.

Comment: Ah I see, I think you actually want the `FourierSinTransform`.

Comment: @chuy Could you explain the difference?

Comment: @chuy `FourierSinTransform` is only applicable if I want $\omega$ as a variable. In my case it is not it is a function or a constant as it is a resonance frequency.

Comment: Mathematica uses the following definition for the Fourier transform: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } f (t) e^{i \omega t} dt$.  The Sine transform is:  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\int _{0}^{\infty } f(t) \sin(\omega t) dt$.  Note the limits of integration.

Comment: @ I understand that, but that isn't helpful if I want to have control over the argument of the sine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92315/discussion-between-chuy-and-quantumpenguin).